# IIS Rewrite Global Rule working on Default Document Only

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

Migrating servers and experiencing an issue with **URL Rewrite** in IIS. The rule works perfectly on our prior servers, but the rule only functions correctly on the default document at the base domain address. The rule is configured as a global rule within IIS.

Rule **works** at: domain.com/

Rule **fails** at: domain.com/any-address-here

Rule details:
*We are matching everything, taking the incoming IP address and passing it to our header. This was configured within IIS and verified within the (/Windows/System32/insetsrv/config/applicationHost.config) file. Server software: Windows 2012R2. Using IIS 8.5.9600.16384 and Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.*

```
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_X_Forwarded_For}" pattern="^([0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{0,3})(.)*$" />
</conditions>
<serverVariables>
    <set name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="{C:1}" />
</serverVariables>
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Could you see that X_forwarded_for header when you access other URL instead of default document? Have you tried to clean browser cache. It sounds like x_forwarded_for was not added in the request header.  Please enable failed request tracing and check this.Besides, have you tried to set action type to none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple workaround, not a fix**. Global rules were simply not being fully recognized in IIS, so the rules were re-configured as Distributed rules. IIS then recognized the rules, but we were receiving 500 error messages. We needed to add Server Variables to complete the rewrites successfully.

Side-note. We had installed URL Rewrite as a standalone application from the Microsoft website but after reading about how this could be problematic - we re-installed the URL Rewrite application via the Web Platform Manager as recommended. This had no effect on the Global Rule vs Default Document rewrite issue above.